# Yii2 rest api update throws object conversion error

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-basic-app, yii-rest

I am working with `Yii2 REST api` and using `Authorisation : Bearer` for authentication.

I have a model `Event` and only 2 actions `Create` and `Update` but my `Update`action is not working fine and throws Object Class conversion error.

I am using following code for finding `Event` model with mixed condition.

```
public function actionUpdate($id)
{
    $params=$_REQUEST;
    /*Following line throws error */
    $model = Event::find()->where(['event_id'=>$id])->andWhere(['partner_id'=> Yii::$app->user->identity]);

    if($model !== null){

        $model->attributes=$params;
        $model->partner_id = Yii::$app->user->id;
        $model->updated_date = time();

        if ($model->save()) {

            $this->setHeader(200);
            echo json_encode(array('status'=>1,'data'=>array_filter($model->attributes)),JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

        }

    }

}
```

The error is something like this

> Object of class api\modules\v1\models\User could not be converted to string

I cant figure out why it says i have created object of `User` class.

Answer (score 2):

```
Yii::$app->user->identity
```

is object you should use

```
Yii::$app->user->identity->id
```

so final line will be:

```
$model = Event::find()->where(['event_id'=>$id])->andWhere(['partner_id'=> Yii::$app->user->identity->id]);
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your `andWhere()`, you are trying to assign `partner_id` an `object` viz. `Yii::$app->user->identity`, so this is where your code is breaking. And do not use `json_encode` when you can use Yii's response format `Response::FORMAT_JSON`, so your code would be like:

```
public function actionUpdate($id)
{
    \Yii::$app->response->format = yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON; // formatting response in json format
    $params= json_decode(\Yii::$app->request->rawBody, 1);
    /*Following line throws error */
    $model = Event::find()->where(['event_id'=>$id])->andWhere(['partner_id'=> Yii::$app->user->identity->id]);

    if($model !== null){

        $model->attributes=$params;
        $model->partner_id = Yii::$app->user->id;
        $model->updated_date = time();

        if ($model->save()) {

            $this->setHeader(200);
            return array('status'=>1,'data'=> $model); // you can simply use $model

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: thank you for your time but that isn't  my problem at the moment though.

Comment: I think the problem is in your `andWhere()` condition. You have used `Yii::$app->user->identity` where `identity` is an complete object which has data about logged in user. So it should be like `Yii::$app->user->identity->anyAttributeFromUserTable`

Comment: i think that was the problem but with the update action i am having problem with `PUT` and `PATCH` request. I dont seem to get any data sent via `PUT` request.

Comment: You shoudn't be using `$_REQUEST`, as you `$_REQUEST` only returns `GET`, `POST`, `COOKIE` data. Because you are using `PUT` or `PATCH` requests I assume you are using `JSON` as a request body, so you should use ` \Yii::$app->request->rawBody`.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is here:

`andWhere(['partner_id'=> Yii::$app->user->identity])`

You ARE attempting to convert a user object (`Yii::$app->user->identity`) to a string. Instead, you need to use the user's id (`Yii::$app->user->identity->id`) which is a string.